# Have a flexbox hidden like display:none and then show it later

Tags: jquery, css, flexbox

My issue is, I have a flexbox

```
<style>
  .popup {
    height:50%;
    width:50%;
    background-color: rgba(99,148,236,0.7);
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 5vw;
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
align-content: space-evenly;
    }
    .popup svg line {
    stroke-width: 2;
    stroke: white;
    fill: none;
}
</style>
<html>
<span id='save_popup'>
<span style='display:flex;flex-direction:row;align-items:center;z-index:22;width:100%;height:100%;'>
<span style='display:flex;flex-direction:column;justify-content: center;align-items:center;z-index:22;width:100%;height:100%;'>
 <span class='popup' style='z-index:22;'>
    <svg id='close_popup' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="2vw" height="2vw" style='z-index:23;position:relative;margin-top:4vh;margin-left:90%;'>
    <line class="a" x1="0" y1="1vw" x2="1vw" y2="0"></line>
    <line class="b" x1="1vw" y1="1vw" x2="-1vw" y2="-1vw"></line>
    </svg>
    <p id='savings_popup_p1' style='font-size:3vw;margin:auto;'>You Saved</p>
    <p id='savings_popup_p2' style='margin:auto;font-family:roboto;max-width:55%;'></p>
    <p id='savings_popup_p3' style='margin:auto;font-family:roboto;max-width:55%;0.9em;'></p>
    <p id='savings_popup_p4' style='margin:auto;font-family:roboto;font-size:0.9em;'>*This is a preliminary estimate, please contact us to discuss more</p>
 </span>
</span>
</span>
</span>
</html>
```

I want to have it hidden, but visibility:hidden; means it still messes up the positioning of the rest of the page when the preloader comes up:

```
<div id='preloader_cover' style='display:flex;flex-direction:column;background-color:black;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:1000;'>
 <div id='preloader_circle' style='display:inherit;border-radius:50%;border:3px solid white;margin:auto;width:18vw;height:18vw;
 background-color:cornflowerblue;'>
    <img id='preloader_logo' src='logo.png' style='margin:auto;width:10vw;height:10vw;'/>
 </div>
 <p id='preloader_p' style='margin: 10vh auto;font-size:4vh;font-family:Montserrat;color:white;'>Loading assets..</p>
 <progress id='preloader_prog' max='100' value='10' style='margin: 5vh auto;height:2vh;width:60%;border-radius:0.8vh;color:white;background-color:background-color:rgba(99,148,236,0.7);
 gray;opacity:0.9;'></progress>

</div>
```

using .hide() and .show() work the same behind the scenes, and I can't use normal display:block for other reasons.

using display:none; in the style, then

```
 $('#save_popup').css('display','flex');
```

doesn't work either, I need to have this working as you'd expect, ie, the preloader covers full screen, the css acts like the popup isn't on the page at all, not just hidden.

but with the ability to toggle it showing on screen, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Does this codepen answer your question?

```
<style>
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
}

nav div {
}


</style>
<script>
var textFieldVisible = true;

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {

  $('input').toggleClass('hidden');

});
</script>
<html>
<nav>
  <div>
    <span>Item 1</span>
  </div>
  <button>Click it</button>
  <input value="Potato brains"/>
  <div>
    <span>Item 2</span>
  </div>
</nav>
</html>
```